# Lost focus from input when click icon to clear it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to implement clearing input by clicking on icon. JSX is

```
<div><input type="text" value={someValueFromState}/><SomeIconComponent onClick={()=> clearInput()}/></div>
```

Icon is hidden by default and shown when input focused. However at the moment of click on icon input gets his focus lost and icon becomes hidden again, making register `click` event impossible. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: I think a prevent default on the icon click should prevent the focus lost

Comment: focus switch on icon. you have to name your input and in your business logic that clear content set focus back to the input

Comment: It is not possible to keep the focus on the input and to click on the icon. The icon gets the focus on the mouse down, while the click event is fired on the mouse up. A "workaround", or rather a hack, would be to have a delay before hiding the icon when the input loses the focus, which will allow you to click it before it disappears.

Comment: you mean show icon not by css :focus pseudo class but with javascript onFocus ?